# Can't filter value inside a string

Tags: json, syntax-error, jq

I need to parse a json with the following format

```
{
  "meta": {
    "rc": "ok"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "average_wifi_utilization": {
        "total": 21.928571428571427,
        "na": 9.035714285714286,
        "ng": 34.82142857142857
      },
      "devices_status": {
        "uap": {
          "adopted": 28,
          "connected": 28,
          "disconnected": 0,
          "pending": 0,
          "disabled": 0
        },
        "usw": {
          "adopted": 2,
          "connected": 2,
          "disconnected": 0,
          "pending": 0
        },
        "ugw": {
          "adopted": 0,
          "connected": 0,
          "disconnected": 0,
          "pending": 0
        }
      },
      "wifi_score": {
        "client_score_avg": 81,
        "clients_with_poor_score": 8,
        "clients_with_fair_score": 3,
        "clients": 99,
        "retry_rate": 0,
        "signal": -61,
        "latency": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract value from "client_score_avg" key.

I'm able to extract first level of info with:

```
cat file.json | jq '.data'
```

However, when I try next step

```
cat file.json | jq '.data.[0]'
```

I get an error message:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: jq is telling you what you did wrong when it says: `unexpected '['`. To solve the problem, you should either omit the immediately preceding period, or use the unabbreviated syntax: `.data | .[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for that. That also worked indeed: "cat file.json | jq '.data | .[0].wifi_score.client_score_avg'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to do below. If your `data[]` array contains multiple entries, specify the index inside the `[..]` part. In your case, the below filter is same as specifying the index as `0` inside the `[..]`

```
jq '.data[].wifi_score.client_score_avg' file.json
```